# Regex with +(plus) and space pattern

Tags: php, regex, cpu-word

I have following sentence

```
"my hooorrrr sssee strongggg"
```

my regex is :

```
"(h+o+r+s+e+) s+t+r+o+n+g+"
```

it's only valid/match when the sentence is :

```
"my hooorrrrsssee strongggg"
```

any body can help ?

i want to match no matter the space between word.

```
example : "my h ooo rrr rss    se eee    stttro ngggg"
```

and the other problem is when the some character replaced by number, like bellow :

```
"my h 0o0 rrr rs555sss    se ee333    stttr0 ngggg"

a replaced by 4
b replaced by 8
s replaced by 5
i replaced by 1
o replaced by 0
```

any body can help ?

Thanks

Comment: Should `horsestrong` (without any space between horse and strong) also match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `*` (space, asterisk) to allow optional spaces.

```
(h[h ]*o[o ]*r[r ]*s[s ]*e[e ]*)s[s ]*t[t ]*r[r ]*o[o ]*n[n ]*g[g ]*
```

You may also want to consider matching any whitespace with `\s` (which includes tab, for example) instead of just space.

To allow numbers or letters use a character class such as `[0o]`.

```
(h[h ]*[o0][o0 ]*r[r ]*[s5][s5 ]*[e3][e3 ]*)[s5][s5 ]*t[t ]*r[r ]*[o0][o0 ]*n[n ]*g[g ]*
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. "(h+ *o+ *r+ *s+ *e+) +s+ *t+ *r+ *o+ *n+ *g+" is valid when the sentence is "my h ooo rrr rss    se eee    stttro ngggg"

Comment: but (h+ *[o0]+ *r+ *[s5]+ *[e3]+) +[s5]+ *t+ *r+ *[o0]+ *n+ *g+ not valid when the sentence is "my h 0o0 rrr rs555sss    se ee333    stttr0 ngggg"

Comment: This does not match when there is letter, space, same letter, like `hooorss sseee`

Comment: Billy right, it not match with "my h 0o0 rrr rs555sss    se ee333    stttr0 ngggg"

Comment: what the different between this regex "(h[h ]*[o 0 *]*r[r ]*[s 5 ]*[e 3]*) [s 5]*t[t ]*r[r ]*[o 0]*n[n ]*g[g ]*" ?

Comment: That would also match `hrse` and `h rse` and `hrtrng`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match whitespace then you need to include that in the regex. `\s` is the pattern that matches whitespace characters (that's space, tab, newline characters).

`r+` will match one or more `r` characters but will NOT look for whitespace.

`r+\s*` with match one or more `r` characters followed by zero or more whitespace characters.

You can build the rest of your expression from there.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED 2**:

Based on the info in your question, you can use (updated to catch the cases that Tim Pietzcker  pointed out!):

```
[h][h ]*[o0][o 0]*[r][r ]*[s][s 5]*[e3][e 3]*[s5][s 5]*[t][t ]*[r][r ]*[o0][o 0]*[n][n ]*[g][g ]*
```

I just realized that this makes the answer the same as Mark Byers, though!

Comment: but it allow to enter any digit word, i just only want a replaced digit thank i listed in my question :)

Comment: Please note that you can also restrict the numbers that are allowed for each letter by simply swapping \d (any number 0-9) with the letters, like [e 3]+.

Comment: This also matches `12345678901` or `h r e t o g` and many more.

Comment: Fixed to match the particular examples. The original answer was meant to be more general so OP could alter it as needed. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It still matches a string that consists entirely of spaces (and many other invalid strings).

Answer (score 1):

This matches each letter, followed by zero or more of the same letter or space

```
h[h ]*o[o ]*r[r ]*s[s ]*e[e ]*s[s ]*t[t ]*r[r ]*o[o ]*n[n ]*g[g ]*
```

With numbers as you specified... (e = 3, o = 0, s = 5)

```
h[h ]*[o0][o 0]*r[r ]*[s5][s 5]*e[e 3]*[s5][s 5]*t[t ]*r[r ]*[o0][o 0]*n[n ]*g[g ]*
```

Comment: +1: Close, but it fails on the '0o0' because the number comes first.

Comment: Now I think it matches all cases, yes.